# Why does Laravel eager loading not work with object functions?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

```
$jobs = Job::with(['topics', 'topic'])->get();

// This works as intented, does not make extra queries.
foreach ($jobs as $job) {
   $job->topics;
}

// This code produces extra queries even tho "topic" is loaded above.
foreach ($jobs as $job) {
   $job->getLogo();
}

// Function in Job Model
function getLogo() {
   return $this->topic->getLogo();
}

// Function in Topic Model
function getLogo() {
   return $this->logo;
}
```

Even though `$job` has loaded `topic` it still makes extra queries. How do I resolve this?

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: What does the `getLogo` function look like in the `Topic` model?

Comment: It is the one below this commented line.
// Function in Job Model

Comment: That function is calling the `getLogo` function on the `Topic` model, so would need to see that function as well.

Comment: It just returns $this->logo, added it in the question as well.

Comment: Can you update the question with the queries being made.

Comment: Wow, okay, it was my bad. I had 2 different Job queries. I was using the one without "with". *facepalm* Now it works as intented. Thank you for your time Matt!